# when the android gradle plugin update to 3.1.0 from 3.0.1,error happened,gradle code is for fixed resources id

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

previous code is(this is the public-xml.gradle that for public.xml fixed resources id)

```
afterEvaluate {  
    for (variant in android.applicationVariants) {  
        def scope = variant.getVariantData().getScope()  
        String mergeTaskName = scope.getMergeResourcesTask().name  
        def mergeTask = tasks.getByName(mergeTaskName)  

        mergeTask.doLast {  
            copy {  
                int i=0  
                from(android.sourceSets.main.res.srcDirs) {  
                    include 'values/public.xml'  
                    rename 'public.xml', (i++ == 0? "public.xml": "public_${i}.xml")  
                }  

                into(mergeTask.outputDir)  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

now the error is

```
No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl.getMergeResourcesTask()is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getMergeJavaResourcesTask()
```

I check the code for VariantScopeImp.java,find that in 3.0.1 the code is

```
 @Nullable private AndroidTask<MergeResources> mergeResourcesTask;
```

in 3.1.0 the code is

```
@Nullable private MergeResources mergeResourcesTask;
```

when I chage the public-xml.gradle code to

```
def scope = variant.getVariantData().getScope()
def mergeTask = scope.mergeResourcesTask
```

the new error is

```
Cannot invoke method doLast() on null object
```

What should I do for it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

try:
`def mergeTask = variant.getMergeResources()`
work for 3.1.4